# Showing Images in PHP

Tags: php

I want to show images residing inside a directory in PHP
The code which I wrote was

```
<?php

$dir = opendir("upload");


while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false)
  {
  echo "filename: " . $file . "<br />";

  echo "<a href='shoe.php?image_name=".$file."'> <img src='upload/".$file[0]."' width='150' height='150' /></a></td>";

  }
closedir($dir);
?>
```

Here the images are not displayed. Only a frame comes for that image and the actual image is not displayed inside that. 
Where I have went wrong? Can any one please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `$file[0]` with `$file`, as `$file` is not an array and that will only return the first character of the string.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP Glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) makes it much easier to list directories. You can do something like

```
$image = glob("*.jpg")
foreach ($image as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: amosrivera: Thanks amosrivera

Answer (score 0):

why $file[0]??? $file is correct:

```
<?php

        $dir = opendir("upload");

        while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false)
          {
          echo "filename: " . $file . "<br />";

          echo "<a href='shoe.php?image_name=".$file."'> <img src='upload/".$file."' width='150' height='150' /></a>";

          }
        closedir($dir);
    ?>
```